# Disable the postback on an <ASP:LinkButton>

Tags: asp.net, asplinkbutton

I have an ASP.NET linkbutton control on my form. I would like to use it for javascript on the client side and prevent it from posting back to the server. (I'd like to use the linkbutton control so I can skin it and disable it in some cases, so a straight up  tag is not preferred).

How do I prevent it from posting back to the server?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

ASPX code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="someID" runat="server" Text="clicky"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        someID.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return false;");
    }
}
```

What renders as HTML is:

```
<a onclick="return false;" id="someID" href="javascript:__doPostBack('someID','')">clicky</a>
```

In this case, what happens is the onclick functionality becomes your validator. If it is false, the "href" link is not executed; however, if it is true the href will get executed. This eliminates your post back.

Comment: `<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton5" runat="server" OnClick="A_Click" CssClass="linkOff" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>` and adding the above, when clicking nothing happens :/

Comment: perfect, been struggling with this for a while as didn't  want the __postback called instead called some JS. much appreciated.

Answer (score 39):

This may sound like an unhelpful answer ... But why are you using a LinkButton for something purely client-side? Use a standard HTML anchor tag and set its `onclick` action to your Javascript.

If you need the server to generate the text of that link, then use an `asp:Label` as the content between the anchor's start and end tags.

If you need to dynamically change the script behavior based on server-side code, consider `asp:Literal` as a technique.

But unless you're doing server-side activity from the Click event of the LinkButton, there just doesn't seem to be much point to using it here.

Comment: I agree. Primarily, I want to use a skin I've already created for linkbuttons used elsewhere.

Comment: Can you not modify the skin, or base the styles for the given anchor off those used in the skin?

Comment: You might favor a linkbutton even if server postback is disabled when: 1) You still desire the benefit of a control implementing INamingContainer. Example, you have multiple user controls on a page where each contains a LinkButton that needs a unique ID.
2) You want to keep asp client validation.

Comment: Also, sometimes LinkButtons are used as a target control for an ajax extender control

Comment: You may want this to dynamically generate the buttons. However you can use new HtmlGenericControl()

Answer (score 27):

You can do it too

```
...LinkButton ID="BtnForgotPassword" runat="server" OnClientClick="ChangeText('1');return false"...
```

And it stop the link button postback

Comment: It works, but the problem is, if you have some operation going on such as deleting the record after modal pop-up, this doesn't work at all. It just simply refreshes the page. Nothing else.

Answer (score 15):

Just set href="#"

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="myLink" runat="server" href="#">Click Me</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: from what i tested, this will cause the page scrolls up the top.

Answer (score 6):

I think you should investigate using a HyperLink control. It's a server-side control (so you can manipulate visibility and such from code), but it omits a regular ol' anchor tag and doesn't cause a postback.

Answer (score 6):

Just been through this, the correct way to do it is to use:

1. `OnClientClick`
2. `return false`

as in the following example line of code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnNext" runat="server" OnClientClick="findAllOccurences(); return false;" />
```

Answer (score 4):

In C#, you'd do something like this:

```
MyButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "put your javascript here including... return false;");
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid refresh of page, if the `return false` is not working with `asp:LinkButton` use

```
href="javascript: void;"
```

or

```
href="#"
```

along with `OnClientClick="return false;"`

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkPrint" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" href="javascript: void;"
        OnClientClick="javascript:self.print();return false;">Print</asp:LinkButton>
```

Above is code will call the browser print without refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

call java script function on onclick event.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of implement the attribute:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page{
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    someID.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return false;");
 }}
```

Use:

```
OnClientClick="return false;"
```

inside of asp:LinkButton tag

Answer (score 1):

Something else you can do, if you want to preserve your scroll position is this:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="someId" href="javascript: void;" Text="Click Me" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an empty ajax update panel and wire the linkbutton's click event to it?  This way only the update panel will get updated, thus avoiding a postback and allowing you to run your javascript

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `OnClientClick`?

```
var myLinkButton = new LinkButton { Text = "Click Here", OnClientClick = "JavaScript: return false;" };

<asp:LinkButton ID="someID" runat="server" Text="clicky" OnClientClick="JavaScript: return false;"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the jquery ready function you can do something like below -

```
var hrefcode = $('a[id*=linkbutton]').attr('href').split(':');
var onclickcode = "javascript: if`(Condition()) {" + hrefcode[1] + ";}";
$('a[id*=linkbutton]').attr('href', onclickcode);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Since the OP did not mention JQuery, your answer is slightly off-topic.  To make the answer better, you could include additional context about how to incorporate JQuery here.  On the other hand, since the question was asked and answered (many times) 5 years ago, only very on-topic answers would be useful at this point.

Answer (score -1):

You might also want to have the client-side function return false.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="button" Text="Click Me" OnClick="myfunction();return false;" AutoPostBack="false" />
```

You might also consider:

```
<span runat="server" id="clickableSpan" onclick="myfunction();" class="clickable">Click Me</span>
```

I use the clickable class to set things like pointer, color, etc. so that its appearance is similar to an anchor tag, but I don't have to worry about it getting posted back or having to do the href="javascript:void(0);" trick.

Comment: OnClick binds the server-side event, not the client side event. onclientclick is the client event

Answer (score -1):

No one seems to be doing it like this:

```
createEventLinkButton.Attributes.Add("onClick", " if (this.innerHTML == 'Please Wait') { return false; } else {  this.innerHTML='Please Wait'; }");
```

This seems to be the only way that works.

Answer (score -1):

use html link instead of asp link and you can use label in between html link for server side 
control